# How would one return a value from a private method to a public method

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm creating a program in ruby which I'm  new to the language and was wondering how I would return the data from a private method to a public method so when the method is called upon the data is shown

I've looked around online but with being new to the language I'm finding it hard to transfer what I'm seeing to what I need in my code

```
def display
    # return calcutalateFrequencies data here
end

private

def calculateFrequencies
  @text = text.downcase.chars.each do |c|
    next if c =~ /\s/
    @letters[c] += 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just call the private method in the public method.

```
def display
  calculateFrequencies
end
```

A private method is just a method that can ONLY be called by other methods in the object, so the above is the only way `calculateFrequencies` would work (excepting if you were using special methods like `send`)

Comment: I've tried just using that in the display method, but I don't get the required output that I am after I end up getting something on the total opposite side of what I'm looking for.
in the IRB terminal, this is what I end up with.
irb(main):007:0> h.display
NoMethodError: undefined method `with_objects' for #<Enumerator: "hello world!":each_char>Did you mean?  with_object
        from letterHistogram.rb:15:in `calculateFrequencies'
        from letterHistogram.rb:10:in `display'
        from (irb):7
        from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

Comment: @modzking4  I think If private method is called then your question is solved.

Answer (score 3):

It could be done in many different ways. Since you are setting instance variables, you might use them or return the result as is.

[I have slightly modified the code to look more rubyish.]

```
def display
  puts calculateFrequencies("foo bar")
  # or puts @letters
end

private

def calculateFrequencies(text)
  @text = text
  @letters =
    text.downcase.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |c, letters|
      next if c == " "
      letters[c] += 1
    end
end
```

Comment: when running this in IRB on my mac, when I call for the display method even when there has been a string passed that it needs to calculate the frequencies for I'm getting the response nil

Comment: If you want to return the frequencies, remove `puts`.

Comment: what would I put in the place of the "foo bar" at the end of the calculated frequencies that would cause an error when running in IRB

Comment: its not actually calculating the amount of characters that are used in the string when i call for the display method, i get this.  irb(main):007:0> h.display
NoMethodError: undefined method `with_objects' for #<Enumerator: "hello world!":each_char>
Did you mean?  with_object
        from letterHistogram.rb:15:in `calculateFrequencies'
        from letterHistogram.rb:10:in `display'
        from (irb):7
        from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

Comment: Sure it does. You’d better check if you can copy-paste the above without bringing errors (hint: `with_object` method should not have trailing ”s”.)

Comment: I have checked over the code and removed the "s" at the end of withobject but now I'm getting something else than what I'm after, in the IRB terminal I'm now getting this.
    h.display
    NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
        from LetterHistogram.rb:17:in `block in calculateFrequencies'
        from LetterHistogram.rb:15:in `each_char'
        from LetterHistogram.rb:15:in `with_object'
        from LetterHistogram.rb:15:in `calculateFrequencies'
        from LetterHistogram.rb:10:in `display'
        from (irb):6
        from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You've changed the question slightly, but things you need to consider:

- methods return the last executed statement.  If you do an `each` as
  the last executed statement (with or without a block) the `each`
  enumerable is returned.
- If the method modifies instance variables
  (as yours do) you may not need to look at what is returned by the
  method, just display the instance variables.

An example of making this work...

```
class FrequencyCalculator

  def initialize(text)
    @text = text
    calculateFrequencies
  end

  def display
    @letters  
  end

  private

  def calculateFrequencies
    @letters = Hash.new(0)
    @text.downcase.chars.each do |c|
      next unless c =~ /\s/  # change from "if" to "unless" otherwise you're skipping letters
      @letters[c] += 1
    end
  end
end
```

And then you could do

```
frequency_calculator = FrequencyCalculator.new('Hello World')
frequency_calculator.display
```

Or more compactly

```
FrequencyCalculator.new('Hello World').display
```